# Velocity of object under central force as radial and tangential components

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, vectors

Consider an object rotating about a point. A central force is always acting on the object. The force can be variable. Now suppose the object is not rotating in a perfectly circular motion but instead moving in an ellipse like path

[image: diagram]

We are required to find the velocity of the object when it is farthest from the central point.
Now the first thought that came to my mind is angular momentum conservation about the central point
$$mv_{⟂} r_{1} = m vr_2$$
(where $v_⟂$ is the initial velocity perpendicular to radius vector)

**This shows that the final velocity (which should be only perpendicular to radius vector) is less than initial perpendicular velocity.**

---

However, another reasoning is that since the force is always acting radially, so there will be acceleration only in radial direction. **This gives that the perpendicular velocity should remain same.** 
which is not the case according to angular momentum conservation


Which method is wrong and why? Is it related to something like rotating frame of reference?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to convert to a rotating frame of reference.

The angular momentum conservation argument is correct.

The radial acceleration being larger or smaller than the magnitude required to be a purely centripetal acceleration, causes an over- or under- rotation of the tangential velocity, and thus there will be a conversion between tangential and radial velocity components. This is then sufficient to explain why the tangential velocity will fail to be constant.

Answer (score 1):

> However, another reasoning is that since the force is always acting radially, so there will be acceleration only in radial direction. **This gives that the tangential velocity should remain same.**

The flaw is in the bolded statement. The radial and tangential directions are not necessarily perpendicular. The only path for which this is true at all points is a circle centered at the "origin". When the radial and tangential unit vectors aren't perpendicular, acceleration in the radial direction also causes tangential acceleration.

Comment: what will be the case if i consider a velocity radially and another perpendicular to it.(edited the word tangential in the question which is misleading)

Comment: The velocity along a direction perpendicular to the radial is also not constant in general, but mainly by virtue of the fact that this direction is constantly changing over the course of the motion. Consider an object travelling in a straight line not passing through the origin, with constant velocity. Even though there is no acceleration, the velocity component perpendicular to the radial direction is always changing.

Comment: yes you are right. still i can't find any reason why that happens, i.e. why frames rotating along with the line joining center and object does not work? the frames are non inertial due to rotation, so maybe i am lacking any pseudo force apart from centrifugal force